# Can I write a script in the command line which iterates though all files in a dir?

Tags: linux, command-line

I would usually write a script for the following command but this time I only want to use it once and therefore would like to write it in the command line.

The script processes all files in a dir.

```
for FILE in *.tif     # grab all the tif files
do
    NEWFILE=test/${FILE}   # create the new file name
    gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:25832  $FILE $NEWFILE
done
```

sorry...I forgot to mention that I did try "
for FILE in *.tif do NEWFILE = test_${FILE} gdal_translate -outsize 50% 50% %FILE %NEWFILE done"
..but it freezes with a > on the next line...as though it is waiting for something else.

Comment: It's not freezing, it's waiting for you to complete the command. The problem is that you omitted the command separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is basically no difference between an interactive command and a script. If you want to put your commands on one line, separate them with semicolons instead of line breaks.

```
for f in *.tif; do gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:25832  $f test/$f; done
```

The secondary prompt is displayed by the shell if your command was not yet complete, such as if you are in the middle of a quoted string or a compound command, or if the previous line ended in a backslash.

Comment: Great!...thanks for all your help! I removed the do; and it worked!

Comment: Yes, the `do` is optional if the loop's body is a single command.

Answer (score 0):

You need semicolons between your script lines.  Try

```
 for FILE in *.tif; do NEWFILE=test/${FILE}; gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:25832 $FILE $NEWFILE; done
```

Comment: I get -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'...i didn´t mention that I´m using linux ubuntu

Comment: @Robert Buckley Turns out I don't need the semicolon after the `do` whenever I try a similar test on my system.  Fixed in the answer